# размер dpi для xserver

Tags: linux, kde, lightdm

В xfce стоит lightdm, и там можно использовать такую команду

```
xserver-command=X -dpi 96
```

А в kde тогда как альтернативу сделать? Например в tizen studio шрифт маленький при установке, но если сделать выше описанную команду, то всё нормально будет. В kde я незнаю как, подскажите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ручками и работает 100%
Настройки -> Внешний вид -> Шрифты: Там пункт "Использовать другой dpi"

В сетях народ еще предлагает:

```
xrandr --dpi ${YOUR_FAVORITE_DPI}
```

[На ArchWiki подробно](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Setting_DPI_manually)

Comment: использовать другой dpi не помогает, он у меня и так установлен какой надо. В xfce решалось это так, в lightdm менял dpi.

Comment: но xrandr помогло, где бы это в автозапуск добавить? В /etc/environment?

Comment: в ~/.bashrc не?

Comment: в bashrc будет выполняться вроде бы каждый раз при входе в систему, или открытии терминала.

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду автозапуск с приложением? Если да, глянь какие сервайсы запускает приложение и впиши в него в секцию [Service] StartExecPre=и полный путь до xrandr --dpi